# Whats a lifecycle aware way to implement a repeating AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-lifecycle

A Fragment needs to refresh data (from network) every n seconds. It needs to stop doing that, when the Fragment is paused. Also, if the network data arrives **after** the fragment is paused, it should be ignored.

Right now, im using a Handler's sendMessageDelayed every n seconds, which creates an AsyncTask, and the AsyncTask posts the response back to the Handler. The Handler then updates the UI.

But, when the Fragment is paused, or the activity has finished, it creates a memory leak.

Also, when the Fragment is no longer active, updating the UI will give a NPE

The code below is pretty naive and full of memory leaks

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        handler.removeMessages(Consts.FETCH_DATA) //stop refreshing when paused
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val msg = handler.obtainMessage(Consts.FETCH_DATA)
        handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 60*1000) //start refreshing again
    }
    val handler = MyHandler()

    inner class MyHandler: Handler(){
        override fun handleMessage(m: Message) {
            val pair = m.obj as Pair<String, Any>
            val command = pair.first
            val data = pair.second
            when(m.what){
                Consts.POPULATE_DATA -> {
                    //findViewById and put data
                    //schedule the next refresh
                    val msg = obtainMessage(Consts.FETCH_DATA)
                    sendMessageDelayed(msg, 60*1000)
                }
                Consts.FETCH_DATA -> {
                    MyAsyncTask(this).execute() 
                    //this sends Consts.POPULATE_DATA to this handler
                    //after a network request
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you have to use AsyncTaskLoader instead of AsyncTask

Comment: @sunilkushwah AsyncTaskLoader. I guess that was it. Any non-messy way to reload the data from it, every n seconds, if I get rid of the handler?

Comment: although handler is also a good approach but if u want to change you can use Timer in android

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it. Before every `sendMessageDelayed` you want to call make `if` statement to check the validation of `Fragment` and `Activity`

```
if(isActivity && isFragment){
sendMessageDelayed(msg, 60*1000);
}
```

then add `isActivity` to your `Activity`

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
boolean isActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        isActivity = true;
    }

 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        isActivity = false;
    }


}
```

And the same for you `Fragment`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
boolean isFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        isFragment= true;
    }

 @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        isFragment= false;
    }

}
```

make `isActivity` and `isFragment` `public static` if you use them in another classes

By this when the `Activity` is running and in `Foreground` the `sendMessageDelayed` will be called, When you Minimize the app or close the activity `sendMessageDelayed` will no longer be called

To relate more see this[image: Activity and Fragment Lifycicle]